# How to get the maximum value of the "Recordset" form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Form structure:
- frm_00_00_MainForm;
- - frm_02_02_Groups_Tbl;
- - frm_reg_GroupsStud_Stud_IdGroup_tbl.
 
Form data source ([frm_reg_GroupsStud_Stud_IdGroup_tbl]) - request.

```
SELECT reg_GroupsStud_Stud. *, Reg_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group
FROM reg_GroupsStud_Stud
WHERE (((reg_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group) = [Forms]! [Frm_00_00_MainForm] [[id_group_frm]));
```

I need to get the maximum value of the [id_stud] field.
So that the code does not process all lines of the request, but only those that are in the form I think this can speed up the code.
For this, I create a "Recordset" form.
 
For this, I try to use the following code:

```
    Private Sub btnMaxValue_Click()
            Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
            Dim studMax As Integer

            Set rst = Me.[frm_reg_GroupsStud_Stud_IdGroup_tbl].Recordset
             studMax = rst.???

End Sub
```

But I do not understand how to get the maximum value of the [id_stud] field.

**Question.**
How to get the maximum value of the "Recordset" form?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sorting the recordset, and then taking the last value. This code is run from the sub form.

```
Private Function GetMax() As Long
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim studMax As Long

    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone

    rst.Sort = "Id_stud"

    rst.MoveLast

    studMax = rst("Id_stud")

    GetMax = studMax

    rst.Close

End Function
```

You need to add error handling and code to check if records are available in the record set. You can assign the value of the `GetMax()` function to any control or VBA logic, from within the sub form.

Comment: Look at the `DMax()` function

Comment: @kismert Could you write more details ...
I watched this option, but I do not understand how to apply it.

Comment: The `DMax()` function will only work against tables and queries. Not running recordsets in forms. For this to work, you would need to create a query that mirrors the results of your subform. Then use `Dmax("FieldName","QueryName")` to get the value from the query.

Comment: @jbud  So that the code does not process all the lines of the request, but only those displayed in the form I made a "Recordset" in which the lines are displayed, only the forms.
Will it speed up the code?

On the other hand, the number of rows that are in the query is equal to the rows that are displayed in the form.
Because the query executes `WHERE ((((reg_GroupsStud_Stud.id_group) = [Forms]! [Frm_00_00_MainForm] [[id_group_frm]))`

Therefore, the `idStudMax = DMax("id_stud", "reg_GroupsStud_Stud_IdGroup")
` code will also be executed quickly.

I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, if your query is displaying the same results as your sub form, then the Dmax function will return the same results as the code provided.

Comment: @jbud because the form is based on a query/recordset, there is nothing your function does that can't be done with a `DMax()`. It would probably be faster, too, as a `rst.Sort` followed by a `rst.MoveLast` will likely take longer than a Max aggregate query.

Comment: @kismert you're right in this case. The function will work fine if the sub form was linked to master form. Since this is not the case then the `Dmax() ` solution is much cleaner.